# Yahtzee 3 of a kind! VB

Tags: vb.net

i'm working on a yahtzee game for my intro to VB class in school. i've gotten through most of the program, and am down to only a few more sets. right now, however, i'm stuck on the three of a kind set, and the four of a kind set. right now i'm working on my 3oak set.

rdb3OAK - a radiobutton the user will check if they plan to put the dice towards 3 of a kind

randnum1-5 - each of the five dice's values

lbl3OAK - the label that the points awarded for 3 of a kind will be shown in

here's the code i have:

```
        '3 of a kind
        If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum1 = randnum2 = randnum3 Then
            lbl3OAK.Text = randnum1 + randnum2 + randnum3 + randnum4 + randnum5
            rdb3OAK.Enabled = False
        End If
        If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum1 = randnum2 = randnum4 Then
            lbl3OAK.Text = randnum1 + randnum2 + randnum3 + randnum4 + randnum5
            rdb3OAK.Enabled = False
        End If
        If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum1 = randnum2 = randnum5 Then
            lbl3OAK.Text = randnum1 + randnum2 + randnum3 + randnum4 + randnum5
            rdb3OAK.Enabled = False
        End If
        If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum1 = randnum3 = randnum4 Then
            lbl3OAK.Text = randnum1 + randnum2 + randnum3 + randnum4 + randnum5
            rdb3OAK.Enabled = False
        End If
        If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum1 = randnum3 = randnum5 Then
            lbl3OAK.Text = randnum1 + randnum2 + randnum3 + randnum4 + randnum5
            rdb3OAK.Enabled = False
        End If
        If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum1 = randnum4 = randnum5 Then
            lbl3OAK.Text = randnum1 + randnum2 + randnum3 + randnum4 + randnum5
            rdb3OAK.Enabled = False
        End If
        If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum2 = randnum3 = randnum4 Then
            lbl3OAK.Text = randnum1 + randnum2 + randnum3 + randnum4 + randnum5
            rdb3OAK.Enabled = False
        End If
        If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum2 = randnum3 = randnum5 Then
            lbl3OAK.Text = randnum1 + randnum2 + randnum3 + randnum4 + randnum5
            rdb3OAK.Enabled = False
        End If
        If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum2 = randnum4 = randnum5 Then
            lbl3OAK.Text = randnum1 + randnum2 + randnum3 + randnum4 + randnum5
            rdb3OAK.Enabled = False
        End If
        If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum3 = randnum4 = randnum5 Then
            lbl3OAK.Text = randnum1 + randnum2 + randnum3 + randnum4 + randnum5
            rdb3OAK.Enabled = False
        End If
```

there's an if statement for each possible combination of three dice equaling the same number. in theory this works, but in practice it does not. i'm not getting any errors at all, so i don't know what is going wrong.

i'm new to programming, so be kind to me!

any help offered would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain this a little better?  From what I see, no matter what happes you're going to add up all 5 dice and set rdb3OAK.Enabled to be False.  There's nothing here that's going to throw an error under any circumstance, unless you forgot to include that piece of code?

Comment: right, because a 3oak just checks to see that 3 dice are the same, and then adds the total of all the dice. after that, i don't want rdb3oak to be able to be chosen a second time, so the button is disabled. if the circumstances of the IF aren't met, then it skips it and moves to the next one. should i be using IfElse instead of separate IF's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do "a = b = c" like that.  You'll need to do "a=b And b=c".  For example, change this:

```
If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum1 = randnum2 = randnum3 Then
```

To this:

```
If rdb3OAK.Checked = True And randnum1 = randnum2 And randnum2 = randnum3 Then
```

I'm a bit rusty on VB, so you may also need to use "==" instead of "=".  (In some languages, "=" is assignment and "==" is comparison.)

Comment: Technically, in the statement "if a=b=c Then", everything after the first equal sign is evaluated first. That is, b=c is evaluated first.  That results as either true or false.  So the "if" statement becomes "if a=true then" or "if a=false then". At that point, that comparison is done ("is a true?" or "is a false?"), and you get your result. And that result is not what you want!

Comment: I'd thumbs up your comment if i could (not enough rep, I guess.) 

So what you're saying is that it should work if i change it to what you suggested?

Comment: it worked! well, sort of. i also had to add an Else after each If to have it do nothing and move on to the next If and check to see if that one worked. thanks again!

Comment: I'm surprised about the "Else" statements, but I'm glad it got working! Thanks for marking my answer as the correct one. :)